# I'm having problems using a Singleton to pass an array in Objective-c. (code included)

Tags: objective-c, arrays, view, uiviewcontroller, singleton

So I'm creating an array called fruits which I would like to share between multiple views.  This is my code:

```
#import <foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface MyManager : NSObject {
    NSMutableArray *fruits;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *fruits;
+ (id)sharedManager;
@end

#import "MyManager.h"
static MyManager *sharedMyManager = nil;
@implementation MyManager
@synthesize fruits;
#pragma mark Singleton Methods
+ (id)sharedManager {
    @synchronized(self) {
        if (sharedMyManager == nil)
            sharedMyManager = [[self alloc] init];
    }
    return sharedMyManager;
}
- (id)init {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        fruits = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}
-(void) dealloc{
    self.fruits = nil;
    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

Now I'm using the following code so that I can use workouts in the new view

```
#import "MyManager.h"
@interface Chest : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet MyManager *fruits;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet MyManager *fruits;
-(IBAction) goToList: (id) sender;
@end
```

When a button is clicked, goToList is called, and I populate my array, fruits

```
#import "Chest.h"
@implementation Chest
@synthesize fruits;
-(IBAction) goToList:(id)sender{
    MyManager *fruits = [MyManager sharedManager];
    NSString *filePath;
    NSString *fileContents;
    filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"chest_strength" ofType:@"csv"];
        fileContents = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
        fruits = [fileContents componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
}
```

When I output the elements of *fruits in this view, everything works fine.  Now when I try to access this same variable in the other view, it says the array is null.  Here's the code for the second view:

```
@interface List : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet MyManager *fruits;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet MyManager *fruits;
@end

#import "List.h"
#import "MyManager.h"
@implementation List
@synthesize fruits
NSLog(@"%@", fruits);  //This is the part that isn't displaying correctly.  I'm getting a null here
```

So my question is, how do I do this so that I can get the array fruits that I populated in Chest and use it in List so that I can display the contents of the array in that view?

Thank you to everybody who answers.  This problem is seriously bogging me down and I need to finish this project ASAP.  Much appreciated.

Comment: Is your array named `workouts` or `fruits`?  The code example you've given is not internally consistent.

Comment: In chest.m you are assigning an NSArray* to fruits, which is of type MyManager*. You want to assign it to fruits.fruits instead.

Comment: Your static var sharedMyManager is global. This is not exactly what the singleton pattern is about. You sould declare it as class variable; Just move it down to after the implementaiton statement so that it is part of MyManager rather than global. Sorry, this does not anwer your question.

Comment: @Hermann: It's not global, it's `static`. Declaring a file-level variable as `static` restricts its visibility to that file. It doesn't need to be inside the `@implementation` block, and putting it there would not change its visibility, nor would it turn it into a class variable, since there are no such things in ObjC.

Comment: Iulius, thanks. It is good to lean something every day. I'll try that on the next oportunity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've changed a few things in this question but the fundamental problem remains: the array is a property of your singleton, and you are not treating it as such.

Whenever you refer to the array, outside of the singleton, do it like this:

```
[MyManager sharedManager].fruits
```

If you are accessing it frequently, you can create a local ivar, but you certainly wouldn't have it as an IBOutlet, which you are doing in your last code sample. How is that ever going to be set?